# Wordpress Category Page, pagination displaying same post in all the pages

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories

Below is the code of the `category.php` file of WordPress.
The problem is that it's showing the same posts on all the pages in paginations.
Any help in resolving the issue is highly appreciated.

```
    <?php
    if (have_posts()) :
      $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
      $cat_id = $cat->cat_ID;
      $cat_name = $cat->name;
      $cat_slug = $cat->slug;
      $category_link = get_category_link($cat_id);
              $catposts = new WP_Query(array(
                  'posts_per_page' => 10,
                  'offset' => 1,
                  'post_type' => 'post',
                  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                  'tax_query' => array(
                      array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'category',
                          'field' => 'slug',
                          'terms' => $cat_slug,
                      )
                  )
              ));
              if ($catposts->have_posts()) :
                while ($catposts->have_posts()) : $catposts->the_post();

                endwhile;
                ?>
              <div class="pagination paginate">
                <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
              </div>
              <?php
              wp_reset_postdata();
            endif;
            ?>
              <?php
    else :
      get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');
    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: remove offset from the query.

Comment: Thank u @Hemu999, it's solved